# How to change the date format?

Tags: javascript

I am using a date picker, when I select a date I want it to print in "DD-MM-YYYY" (in my text field). If the number is below 10 it is showing 1 or 9 and not 01 or 09 in the text field after selection from the date picker. It's happening for both month and day.

I am using this code for setting the date.

```
var re_date = /^(\d+)\-(\d+)\-(\d+)\s$/;
if (!re_date.exec(str_datetime))

    return alert("Invalid Datetime format: "+ str_datetime);

return (new Date (RegExp.$3, RegExp.$2-1, RegExp.$1, RegExp.$4, RegExp.$5, RegExp.$6));
```

Comment: YOu can extract parts of the date using `.getDay()`, `.getMonth()`, and so on. Next, you can combine those parts into any stirng you like in any order. There is no `.format()` method (or alike) in Javascript that can do this all in one. Listing of all Methods available on `Date` is here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
   function d(str_datetime) {
        var re_date = /^(\d+)\-(\d+)\-(\d+)\s$/;
        if (!re_date.exec(str_datetime))

        return alert("Invalid Datetime format: "+ str_datetime);

        return (new Date (RegExp.$3, RegExp.$2-1, RegExp.$1));
    }

    var b = d('01-01-2014 ');
    b.getDate() +'-'+ (b.getMonth()+1)+'-'+b.getFullYear();
    // Outputs : "1-1-2014"
```

Btw. since your regex is not capturing minutes/seconds you can delete RegExp.$4 > as shown here.
If you need padding 0 then you can use this helper function:

```
function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
```

And change the result to :

```
pad(b.getDate()) +'-'+ pad((b.getMonth()+1))+'-'+b.getFullYear();
```

Comment: i want output as 01-01-2014.after selecting from the date picker.but i am getting 1-1-2014